# How to create array associated with other table

Tags: node.js, postgresql, associations, sequelize.js

I have two tables `units` and `formation`.
Each `formation` may contain up to 6 units.
Now my `formation` have 6 separated columns, each of them associated with `unit`.
Like:

```
let Formation = sequelize.define('formation', {
    /* some fields */
}, {
    classMethods: {
        associate: (m) => {
            Formation.belongsTo(m.unit, {
                as: 'u0', foreignKey: 'unit0'});
            Formation.belongsTo(m.unit, {
                as: 'u1', foreignKey: 'unit1'});
            Formation.belongsTo(m.unit, {
                as: 'u2', foreignKey: 'unit2'});
            Formation.belongsTo(m.unit, {
                as: 'u3', foreignKey: 'unit3'});
            Formation.belongsTo(m.unit, {
                as: 'u4', foreignKey: 'unit4'});
            Formation.belongsTo(m.unit, {
                as: 'u5', foreignKey: 'unit5'});
        }
    }
});
```

Is it possible rewrite this as one column that contains all this 6 elements and each of them associated with `unit`.

Comment: [Foreign key constraint on array member?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60132/foreign-key-constraint-on-array-member)

Comment: Look similar, my problem is in syntax for an array that contains foreign keys.

Comment: This is exactly the same. You search for something like [`integer[] ELEMENT REFERENCES units`](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/1343842863.5162.4.camel@greygoo.devise-it.lan)